# Understanding EKS identity providers in AWS

Tags: amazon-iam, amazon-eks

I created EKS cluster and run a pod with a server with an image from ECR. The problem is the user needs to sign in with some internal sso.

I search a lot and probably I need to somehow setup OpenID Connect. However I couldn't understand how it works with EKS.

EKS Cluster itself has a `OpenID Connect provider URL`. And it has an Authentication tab where I can add `OIDC identity providers`. My guess is first one is related to [IRSA](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/iam-roles-for-service-accounts.html) (whatever it is) and second one allows pod to access specified providers there but... it's only a guess and I cannot completely understand that.

**Why there are two places in EKS cluster with OpenID Connect url and what are they for?** You may assume little knowledge about AWS and auth stuff.

Comment: "The problem is the user needs to sign in with some internal sso." Are you referring to a company SSO through Okta or something? Seemingly that would have to be configured at the _application_ level; this doesn't seem to be something that kubernetes would manage. The OpenID Connect provider URL (et al) is so that kubernetes services (e.g. `external-dns` and `cert-manager` can authenticate into _AWS_ so that they might modify things (e.g. records in route 53).